# Dropdown list in Laravel is not displaying

Tags: php, laravel

Below my drop-down list is not displaying and I don't know where the problem is. Could it be in my SerieController? I want to create an edit/update system but I've had no success.

[image]

**SerieController**

```php
public function edit($id)
{
    $series = Serie::with('marks')->find($id);

    return view('admin.series.edit', compact('series'));
}

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'fk_mark' => 'required'
    ]);

    $series = Serie::with('marks')->find($id);
    $series->name = $request->get('name');
    $series->fk_mark = $request->get('fk_mark');
    $series->save();

    return redirect()->route('series.index')
        ->with('success', 'updated successfully');
}
```

**Mark Model**

```php
class Mark extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name_mark'];

    public function series()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Serie', 'fk_mark');
    }
}
```

**Serie Model**

```php
class Serie extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'fk_mark'];

    public function marks()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Mark', 'fk_mark');
    }
}
```

I have another question. In my view, I have a form. Is the edit ok?

**serie.index.blade**

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('series.destroy', $serie) }}">
    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" href="{{ route('series.edit', $serie->id) }}">Editer</a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be the other way: mark model belongsTo and Series model HasMany, no?

Comment: No, I don't think... My problem is really in my Controller with my 2 methods "edit" and "update". Because my method "create" works.